# Firemonkey FTDI XE7 d2xx.jar drivers

Tags: java, android, delphi, firemonkey, ftdi

I am working on project with FT232RL using d2xx Android drivers, on firemonkey XE7.

Android tablet <-> USB FT232RL card.

I manage to create unit (Androidapi.JNI.d2xx.pas) from d2xx.jar using Java2OP,add it to Libraries, compile and build. But when i try to use some class i only get errors. I try:

```
context:= SharedActivityContext;
D2xxManager := TJD2xxManager.Create; // fragmentation error
devCount := D2xxManager.createDeviceInfoList(context);
```

and

```
D2xxManager :=  TJD2xxManager.JavaClass.getInstance(SharedActivityContext);

devCount := D2xxManager.createDeviceInfoList(SharedActivityContext);
//Java class JD2xxmanager could not be found
```

Created Unit [Androidapi.JNI.d2xx.pas](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2003839/Androidapi.JNI.d2xx.pas)
main form [Unit1](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2003839/Unit1.pas)

Is my Androidapi.JNI.d2xx.pas failing or wrong way to call java bridged class ?
Did anyone manage to do something like this ?

Comment: What are the errors you get?

Comment: In first example I get "fragmentation error" on TJD2xxManager.Create, and App crashed and restart android tablet.

In second example I get "Java class JD2xxmanager could not be found" but much nicer in Android popup window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy D2xx.jar to same directory of code
Follow instruction in [this link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Adding_A_Java_Library_to_Your_Application_Using_the_Project_Manager) to add a Java library file (.jar) to Android application. 
Works like a charm.

Comment: Hi! It's a good way to include the contents of the referenced link in the answer as well. Just in case, the link gets down or broken. :)